# SOAP fault error when using AngularJS to request from SSRS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap, reporting-services

I'm using AngularJS to try to pull down a list of reports from [SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) to display in an iframe. The problem I'm running into is that I am getting a SOAP fault error when doing the POST request.

Here is what the Angular controller looks like that is making the POST.

```
function ReportSSRSController($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.request = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">'
        + '<soap:Body>'
        + '<m:ListChildren xmlns:m="http://example.com/ReportingServer/ReportService2010">'
        + '<m:ItemPath>/reports</m:ItemPath>'
        + '<m:Recursive>false</m:Recursive>' 
        + '</m:ListChildren>' 
        + '</soap:Body>' 
        + '</soap:Envelope>';
    $http({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: '/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx', 
        data: $scope.request, 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer/ListChildren"'
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('In Success');
        $scope.data = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log('In Error');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(config);
    });
}
```

And here is the gist of the SOAP fault error.

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The value for parameter 'ItemPath' is not specified. It is either missing from the function call, or it is set to null.

As you can see in the Angular code, the `ItemPath` is included in the SOAP body in the same namespace as the function call. I can also see it in the console as the output of the `data` variable in the error block. So I'm wondering why it is not able to find that information.

Is there something I'm missing maybe in the way Angular is handling the POST request? Or have I not formulated the SOAP request correctly?

Comment: I suggest you used some SOAP client and make request, and then compare it to the request made using angular for differences.

Comment: @Chandermani That thought occurred to me recently as well. I was hoping that I was close enough in angular that maybe someone could point out the mistake quicker than it would take me to rewrite this using something else. I'll definitely try that though and update the question with any new information I find from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is related to the namespace in the SOAP XML.

When I changed the namespace to

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer
```

to match the SOAP action (minus the command at the end); the request returned a valid SOAP response.

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of SOAP or SSRS though since I'm not very familiar with either.

Comment: Thank you! this was giving me hours of trouble and your solution helped me solve it.